# Append a specific identifier to data in a tab delimited text file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, text

Essentially I have something like this:

```
B3  LPC1030_64571   LPC1283_613422

B2  LPC107_67093    LPC174_1161466  LPC1283_579823  LPC5_2182288  LPC1378_340850    LPC203_5679639  LPC107_67396    LPC107_67535    LPC107_70165    LPC107_77297    LPC107_80176    LPC107_81524    LPC107_88715    AMZ216_267328   AMZ216_268028   

B1  ...
```

For those in each Bx row I want to append *".Bx"

Comment: Could you add example output? Because it is unclear what you want exactly (still in rows? keep the Bx as well? just on stdout or in a file?).

Comment: Sure. To give specific examples, in this dataset for instance I want LPC1030_64571 to be renamed to LPC1030_64571.B3 because it's in the row named B3. And LPC174_1161466 renamed to LPC174_1161466.B2 because it's in the B2 row. @SamuelKirschner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple awk script will do that:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i "." $1}; print}' <infile
```

or more nicely formated:

```
awk '{
        for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)   #NF is the number of fields
        {
            $i = $i "." $1   #$i now is the text in each field exept the first
        }; 
        print                #print the modified fields to stdout
    }' <infile
```